# How does One to Many Relationship in Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I am new to Realm SWift. I want achieve one to many relationship in Swift3.0

I have list of folders and each folder may have list of subfolders. So i create two relam files like below.

**Folder Realm Class**

```
 class FolderRealm: Object {

    dynamic var folderName : String?
    dynamic var createdDate : Date?
    let subFolders = List<SubFolderRealm>()
 }
```

**SubFolder Realm Class**

```
 class SubFolderRealm: Object {

   dynamic var subFolderName : String?
   dynamic var createdDate : Date? 

 }
```

For Adding folder I used following lines of Code

```
let folder : FolderRealm  = FolderRealm()
folder.folderName = searchBarObj.text!
folder.createdDate = Date()
 try! realm.write {
   realm.add(folder)
 }
```

I have doubt, how to add Subfolder data into Folder and Subfolder Realm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this before your `try! realm.write { realm.add(folder) }` line

```
let folder : FolderRealm  = FolderRealm()
folder.folderName = searchBarObj.text!
folder.createdDate = Date()

let subFolder1: SubFolderRealm = SubFolderRealm()
subFolder1.subFolderName = "any string"
subFolder1.createdDate = Date()

let subFolder2: SubFolderRealm = SubFolderRealm()
subFolder2.subFolderName = "any string"
subFolder2.createdDate = Date()

folder.subFolders = [subFolder1, subFolder2]

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(folder)
}
```

Comment: Here folder object already exist. So can i update like below 

try! realm.write {
folder.subFolders = [subFolder1, subFolder2]
}


So here subfolders created and subfolders added into Folder class?

Comment: Nayem, Here im asking Folder objetct is already exist with empty subfolder. Now i want to update my Folder objet with new Subfolder list. so is it good to write like below

try! realm.write {
               folderobjnew.subFolders.append(subfolder)
            }

Comment: Yes! That will do it

Comment: @srinadh glad to hear that. So you should click that little tick mark on the left side of this answer to accept this answer as it solved your problem. **It will help the members who will have this similar issue in the future**

Answer (score 9):

For a start, consider just using only one `Folder` type and not two, no point having a Subfolder object when all the data is the same.

```
class Folder : Object {
    dynamic var folderName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdDate:Date = Date()
}
```

Second, for your case you may want to use [LinkingObjects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/LinkingObjects.html).

```
class Folder : Object {
    dynamic var folderName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdDate:Date = Date()
    dynamic var parentFolder:Folder? = nil

    let subfolders = LinkingObjects(fromType: Folder.self, property: "parentFolder")
}
```

And you'd create objects like this :

```
let parentFolder = Folder()
let subfolder1 = Folder()
let subfolder2 = Folder()

parentFolder.folderName = "whatever"

subfolder1.parentFolder = parentFolder
subfolder2.parentFolder = parentFolder

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write { realm.add([parentFolder, subfolder1, subfolder2])}
```